# Bootstrap modal popup button inside accordion drop down

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-accordion

I'm wondering something simple but intricate..

So, I'm using bootstrap over materialized.
What I'd like to do is put the modal into the accordion, I'm pretty confused on how to do this, I tried some sandboxes for this concept and similar ones but I haven't gotten good results.

```html
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I should be able to click the accordian, the content will come down and the modal button will allow them to access a table of contents / the links to videos, full versions and etc.

I picked bootstrap over materialized because it is more customizable, So in theory this should be feasible, I'm going to tinker with more code.. I have one more thought of how to get this working, I'll see where that lands me, if all goes well I'll post it up! Wish me luck!!

Basically this question inverted:

[Accordion inside popup, colorbox / modal Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25138173/accordion-inside-popup-colorbox-modal-bootstrap#)

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x4D35/)

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I found out what the problem was.. Well one of a few

I didn't have the Jquery initiators in the right file.. my Jquery CDN links where not at the top of the page, and then I installed Jquery this is what my code looks like now

```js
$('#myCollapsible').collapse({
  toggle: false
})

$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#myInput').focus()
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Meditation Stories Heart Center Focus Reflective Visual</title>



<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




</head>
<body>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        t1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
        t2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Button trigger modal -->


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```